# How to measure trajectory regularity?

Tags: algorithms

I have two animal running trajectories. A regular one with repeated back and forth running between point A and B, like the one on top in the figure. The other one is very irregular, animal paused and turned around a lot in the middle.  Is there any algorithm to measure the regularity of a trajectory, like repeated activity on the top?  And compare the extend of regularity between the two trajectories?  Thanks in advance. 
[image]

Comment: Can you rigorously state what determines a "regular path"? In the example given, would a single straight line from A to B be considered more or less regular than the first path in the example? Would a path that goes back and forth N times be more or less regular than a path that does the same thing in the same shape, but N+1 times?

Comment: By 'more regular trajectory', I mean animal run with higher mean speed, less turn back and less pauses in the middle, more laps within the same amount of time. The figure above is for demonstration purpose, since animal can not run straight with constant speed anyway. Thanks.

Comment: One possible measure of a path's "regularity" is called [sinuosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinuosity), which is the ratio of its total arclength by the straight line distance from start to finish. But using this criteria, the regular zig-zag in the first path of the example would have a large sinuosity compared to a path that is a slightly distorted straight line from start to finish.

Comment: The "speed" depends on how you parametrize the path. You can have a parametrization in which straight parts are slow and curves are fast. Using the unit-speed parametrization of the path (which is unique and unambiguous) could help. You could then look for the magnitude of the acceleration (always perpendicular to the speed, that is, the change in the direction/heading along the path). This is closely related to the curvature at each point. If you integrate the total (absolute value/square of) acceleration at all points, you'd only get 0 for a straight line.

Comment: So, lots of possible options. You still need to properly define which characteristics of a path would rank it as more/less irregular than others. I'd advise you to sit down and consider at least a dozen example cases. At least figure which paths would be the most regular and the most irregular.

Comment: Thank you for these helpful information!

Comment: No problem! If you update with more details let me know, so I can check the problem again.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14298/how-to-measure-trajectory-regularity

Answer (score 1):

I think you could measure the curvature of that curve $\gamma(t)$ with $t\in[0,1]$.

First you have to build the derivate (or gradient), by computing:

$$ \gamma'(t) = \left(\frac{\partial \gamma_1}{\partial t},\frac{\partial \gamma_2}{\partial t}\right)\approx\frac{\gamma(t+h)-\gamma(t)}{h}$$

Where you try to choose $h$ as small as possible.
Now you build the second derivative:

$$ \gamma''(t) \approx \frac{\gamma'(t+h)-\gamma'(t)}{h}$$

Now just integrate that thing:

$$ K=\int\limits_{\gamma(\mathbb{R})} \big\Vert\gamma''(t)\big\Vert\text{d}t = \int\limits_{\gamma(\mathbb{R})} \sqrt{\big(\gamma''_1(t)\big)^2+\big(\gamma''_2(t)\big)^2} \text{d} t \approx \sum_{t=0}^{\lfloor\frac{1}{h}\rfloor} \sqrt{\big(\gamma''_1(th)\big)^2+\big(\gamma''_2(th)\big)^2}$$

I think that $K$ will be big if the curve is bending a lot! A straight line for instance has $K=0$. A circle will have bendiness 1.

#### Edit:

As pointed out your need to "walk" the curve by constant speed (if you intend to measure the curve out of a geometrical aspect), hence:
$$\forall t\in[0,1]\quad\quad\big\Vert \gamma'(t)\big\Vert = c\in\mathbb{R}$$

This is done by inverting $s(t):=\Vert\gamma'(t)\Vert$ than you get the desired curve $\widetilde{\gamma}(l) := \gamma(s^{-1}(l))$ for $l\in[0,s(1)]$.

#### Algorithm:

The following code is in python with a simple vector type, so I hope it's readable enought. Given a path by a set of points `P` with `n=len(P)` you could do:

```
v = (P[0]-P[1])/h
k = 0
for i in range(1,n-1):
    p = P[i]
    q = P[i+1]
    w = (p-q)/h
    k += abs((v-w)/h)
    v = w
```

The variable `k` is $K$. If you want to take speed differences out of the computation as pointed out by LucasVB, just normalize `v,w` like this `k+=abs((v/abs(v)-w/abs(w))/h)`. I think it is possible to add some more precision by using more complex numerical analysis, but this is hopefully something that gets you started.

Comment: You need $\gamma(t)$ to be a constant speed parametrization on $t$, otherwise the second derivative will also include a tangential acceleration term that could make $K$ non-zero for a straight line. Dumb example: $\gamma(t) = (t^2,0) \to \gamma''(t) = (2,0)$, so $K = \int_0^1 2 dt = 2$.

Comment: @LucasVB in fact I'm not really sure. If the curve is not parametrizated than you might even measure difference in speed which may be intended.